# Complex query with Django (posts from all friends)

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm new to Python and Django, so please be patient with me.

I have the following models:

```
class User(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
   ...

class Post(models.Model):
   userBy = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='post_user')
   userWall = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='receive_user')
   timestamp = models.DateTimeField()
   post = models.TextField()

class Friend(models.Model):
   user1 = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='request_user')
   user2 = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='accept_user')
   isApproved = models.BooleanField()
   class Meta:
      unique_together = (('user1', 'user2'), )
```

I know that this may not be the best/easiest way to handle it with Django, but I learned it this way and I want to keep it like this.

Now, all I want to do is **get all the post from one person and it's friends**. The question now is how to do it with the Django filters?

I think in SQL it would look something like this:

```
SELECT p.* FORM Post p, Friend f 
WHERE p.userBy=THEUSER OR (
    (f.user1=THEUSER AND f.user2=p.userBy) OR
    (f.user2=THEUSER AND f.user1=p.userBy)
)
```

With no guarantee of correctness, just to give an idea of the result I'm looking for.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
from django.db.models import Q

Post.objects.filter( \
    Q(userBy=some_user) | \
    Q(userBy__accept_user__user1=some_user) | \
    Q(userBy__request_user__user2=some_user)).distinct()
```

**UPDATE**

Sorry, that was my fault. I didn't pay attention to your `related_name` values. See updated code above. Using `userBy__accept_user` or `userBy__request_user` alone won't work because that'll be a reference to `Friend` which you can't compare to to `User`. What we're doing here is following the reverse relationship to `Friend` and then once we're there, seeing if the *other* user on the friend request is the user in question.

This also illustrates the importance of describing reverse relationships appropriately. Many people make the same mistake you've made here and name the `related_name` after the model they're creating the FK to (`User`), when actually, when we're talking about reversing the FK, we're now talking about `Friend`. Simply, your related names would make more sense as something like: `friend_requests` and `accepted_friends`.

Comment: is there a foreign key from User that has to point to Friends ?

Comment: No. The "__friend" bit follows the relationship backwards, since `Friend` has a FK to `User`.

Comment: For more information see the documentation for [lookups that span relationships](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships).

Comment: With this i get a FieldError: "Cannot resolve keyword 'friend' into field."
if i change it to
    ...Q(userBy__accept_user=user_) | Q(userBy__request_user=user_)...

the error is gone but not all posts are showing up

Comment: I believe this will include too many posts (it will include posts from users that 'some_user' has requested to be friends with, regardless of whether they accepted or not, and will include posts from users that have requested to be friends with 'some_user', whether 'some_user' accepted the request or not).  I believe this will work, however:Post.objects.filter(Q(userBy=some_user) | (Q(userBy__accept_user__user1=some_user) & Q(userBy_accept_user__isApproved=True)) | (Q(userBy__request_user__user2=some_user) & Q(userBy_accept_user__isApproved=True))).distinct()

Answer (score 0):

```
(with User u)
friends_u1 = Friend.objects.filter(user1 = u).getlist('user2_id', flat=True)
friends_u2 = Friend.objects.filter(user2 = u).getlist('user1_id', flat=True)
friends_and_user = friends_u1+friends_u2+u.id

Post.objects.filter(userBy__id__in = friends_and_user)
```

Comment: The standard approach is to use `Q` object. Could you clarify _why_ did you choose different approach?

Comment: Where are you getting "the standard approach is to use a Q object"? Nowhere in the documentation does it say that. Also, for a django newbie, this broken out approach may be more easily understandable.

Comment: From experience. You are gathering all IDs first, then you are using it for a query. Consider the case where you would have 500 friends, the query could be enormous. Yes, this solution could be used by Django newbie (or by someone knowing _why_ and _when_ it could be better), but this is not about what is easier to understand, rather what is the best (or at least "good"). When it comes to "standard approach" part: [read the documentation on complex queries in Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects).

Comment: I agree with @Tadeck, but I don't think the downvote was warranted. It's a valid approach here, though it's not the *efficient* approach. The answer could be improved by simply selecting all the ids at once instead of adding them, and then feeding that into the filter. Django will judiciously optimize the query. Of course, you'd have to use `Q` objects to do that, so it sort of defeats the point. Still, some use might be made of it.

Comment: @ChrisPratt: Ok, downvote removed. Hope someone looking for a solution will read the comments before implementing it.

Comment: @ChrisPratt ditto. Thank you. I'll leave it up for the sake of discussion, though yours is much more efficient and, after looking at the OP's sql, would in fact probably be more instinctive for them.