# Django 1.9 migrate for the first time is not creating tables

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I've never had this problem before. I've started countless projects and had no problem when I went to run 'makemigrations" for the first time. In this project I keep getting the error:

> django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such table: accounts_customuser

That's the point, there isn't a table...it's supposed to make one.

I'm not running any fancy databases, it's just sqlite3.

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django_extensions',
    'rest_framework',
    'rest_framework.authtoken',
   # 'djoser',
   # 'django_comments',
   # 'django_comments_xtd',
    'accounts',
    'blog',
]

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}
```

Full TraceBack:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm 4.5.4\helpers\pycharm\django_manage.py", line 41, in <module>
run_module(manage_file, None, '__main__', True)
File "C:\Python27\Lib\runpy.py", line 176, in run_module
fname, loader, pkg_name)
File "C:\Python27\Lib\runpy.py", line 82, in _run_module_code
mod_name, mod_fname, mod_loader, pkg_name)
File "C:\Python27\Lib\runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
exec code in run_globals
File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\newapp\manage.py", line 10, in <module>
execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\newsite\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 353, in execute_from_command_line
utility.execute()
File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\newsite\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 345, in execute
self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\newsite\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 348, in run_from_argv
self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\newsite\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 398, in execute
self.check()
File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\newsite\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 426, in check
include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\newsite\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\registry.py", line 75, in run_checks
new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\newsite\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 13, in check_url_config
return check_resolver(resolver)
File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\newsite\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 23, in check_resolver
for pattern in resolver.url_patterns:
File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\newsite\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 33, in __get__
res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\newsite\lib\site-packages\django\core\urlresolvers.py", line 417, in url_patterns
patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\newsite\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 33, in __get__
res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\newsite\lib\site-packages\django\core\urlresolvers.py", line 410, in urlconf_module
return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
File "C:\Python27\Lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
__import__(name)
File "C:/Users/User/Desktop/newapp\newapp\urls.py", line 21, in <module>
from blog.views import PostViewSet
File "C:/Users/User/Desktop/newapp\blog\views.py", line 14, in <module>
class PostViewSet(ModelViewSet):
File "C:/Users/User/Desktop/newapp\blog\views.py", line 15, in PostViewSet
some_user = CustomUser.objects.get(pk=1)
File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\newsite\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 122, in manager_method
return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\newsite\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 381, in get
num = len(clone)
File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\newsite\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 240, in __len__
self._fetch_all()
File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\newsite\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 1074, in _fetch_all
self._result_cache = list(self.iterator())
File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\newsite\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 52, in __iter__
results = compiler.execute_sql()
File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\newsite\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 848, in execute_sql
cursor.execute(sql, params)
File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\newsite\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 79, in execute
return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)
File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\newsite\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 64, in execute
return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\newsite\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 95, in __exit__
six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\newsite\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 64, in execute
return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\newsite\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 323, in execute
return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such table: accounts_customuser
```

**EDIT #2**

Could the problem be in my PostViewSet? I've never done a complex query before, so I don't know if it's proper syntax. I got this from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12866920/complex-query-with-django-posts-from-all-friends)

```
class PostViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    some_user = CustomUser.objects.get(pk=1)
    queryset = Post.objects.filter(
    Q(poster=some_user) |
    Q(poster__friends__creator=some_user) |
    Q(poster__friendship_creator__friend=some_user)).distinct()
    serializer_class = PostSerializer
```

Comment: `makemigrations` then **`migrate`**

Comment: Please show the full traceback

Comment: Which migration is this happening in? You probably need to add a dependency on accounts.

Comment: I added the full Traceback

Comment: Did you run `makemigrations` first and then `migrate`?

Comment: For me sometimes help if I just comment out the model that you were modifying then makemigrations and migrate, and then undo comments and again makemigrations and migrate. (WARNING: you will lose db data!)

Comment: Yes, I ran makemigrations first.

Comment: I added another edit. Maybe the problem is in my PostViewSet? It's showing up on the Traceback.

Comment: @Alasdair, so I'm getting somewhere. I deleted the blog app, and ran "makemigrations" with just the 'accounts' app, and there were no issues. Now I put 'blog' back into INSTALLED APPS and I get the error: **accounts.models.DoesNotExist: CustomUser matching query does not exist.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your `CustomUser.objects.get(pk=1)` query is running when the URL config is loaded and imports the views, before the tables have even been created. You can fix this by moving the code into a `get_queryset` method.

```
class PostViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    def get_queryset(self):
        some_user = CustomUser.objects.get(pk=1)
        return Post.objects.filter(
            Q(poster=some_user) |
            Q(poster__friends__creator=some_user) |
            Q(poster__friendship_creator__friend=some_user)).distinct()
    serializer_class = PostSerializer
```

Comment: You're the man dude! I initially got this error when I tried your code: _AssertionError: `base_name` argument not specified, and could not automatically determine the name from the viewset, as it does not have a `.queryset` attribute._ but simply adding a base_name to my url **router.register(r'posts', PostViewSet, 'Post')** solved it.